# Why does cmake give undefined references for netcdf with cygwin on windows?

Tags: c, cmake, cygwin, netcdf, clion

I am trying to set up some model code on multiple operating systems using clion 2016.3-1 and its bundled cmake 3.6.2.
On Windows I am using the cygwin environment but I ran into a linking issue I can not resolve. Here is a minimum example of my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netcdf.h>

#define ERRCODE 2
#define ERR(e) {printf("Error: %s\n", nc_strerror(e)); exit(ERRCODE);}

int main() {
  int ncid, varid, dimid, retval;
  size_t nlat;
  char filepath[] = "minimumExample.nc";
  char dimname[64];
  double *latitudes;

  // open nc file
  if ((retval = nc_open(filepath, NC_NOWRITE, &ncid))) ERR(retval);

  // find variable IDs
  if ((retval = nc_inq_varid(ncid, "latitude", &varid))) ERR(retval);

  // find dimension bounds
  if ((retval = nc_inq_vardimid(ncid, varid, &dimid))) ERR(retval);
  if ((retval = nc_inq_dim(ncid, dimid, dimname, &nlat))) ERR(retval);

  // allocate data array
  latitudes = malloc(sizeof(double) * nlat);

  // get data
  if ((retval = nc_get_var_double(ncid, varid, &latitudes[0]))) ERR(retval);

  // close nc file
  if ((retval = nc_close(ncid))) ERR(retval);

  // free data array
  free(latitudes);

  return(0);
}
```

Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(test_examples)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -lnetcdf")

include_directories("/usr/include")
link_directories("/usr/lib")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.c)

add_executable(test_examples ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

However I get a lot of error messages similar to:

```
undefined reference to `nc_open'
```

The binaries and include files are all present in the cygwin environment at the respective folders.
What am I missing?

Comment: Have you installed the needed haders and import libraries ? For nectcdf you need the `libnetcdf-devel` package.

Comment: @matzeri I have all headers and libraries installed. The files `netcdf.h` and `netcdf.dll.a` are in the include and lib directories, respectively.

Comment: it's ofc `libnetcdf.dll.a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors are saying that linker could not find code for that functions: in other words the library is not reachable.

You should use the [CMake target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html) function to link `netcdf` lib.

remove

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -lnetcdf")
```

and add

```
target_link_libraries (test_examples netcdf)
```

Comment: I changed the CMakeLists file accordingly. To do so I tried to add `find_package(netcdf)`. However, this lead cmake to find the libraries of my Anaconda installation. Finally using the filename given in the cygwin environment solved the problem: `find_package(libnetcdf.dll)`